# Serving RTMP video to multiple viewers (also possibly re-encoding)

Tags: video, video-streaming, rtmp, video-encoding

I have a 6-camera security system setup and I'm trying to figure out how to serve the video feeds to multiple off-site viewing stations.

The cameras capture at 1080p and are IP-based. Each one provides 1) a RTMP live feed and 2) a still-image snapshot URL.

The internet connection to this facility is very slow.  Upload speed is approximately 1.5 Mbit.

We have multiple remote locations that want to view the camera feeds simultaneously (i.e. several monitoring stations etc).

I currently have configured a cloud server which retrieves the snapshot images once per minute and serves them to the client viewers, to reduce demands on the facility's bandwidth.  However, I'm wondering if it's possible to stream the RTMP feeds to this cloud server and re-stream (is this a proxy?) from this server to all viewing clients?

Is this something Red5 is good for?  or is there a simpler solution?

Also, it would be nice to convert the stream to a format which is playable natively in most browsers (i.e. Firefox/Chrome/Android/iOS) without requiring a plugin.

I'm aware of rtmpdump and ffmpeg, but not sure how to proceed.

So, two issues:
1) How to capture the RTMP feeds from the cloud server, and "re-serve" them to several viewing clients

2) How to re-encode the feeds for more compatibility with desktop and mobile devices without the need for a flash or other plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule the approach from the originating source to the server will be different than from the server to the viewing clients. In other words the server does not just act as a proxy.

This is because the delivery to the clients may require conversion of the video into a different format, and depending on how important quality and user experience is, even the creation of multiple different bit rate versions of each format to allow for different network conditions.

Serving video to multiple clients and supporting as wide a set of client types as possible is relatively specialist, and there are streaming servers which are designed to do just this. Some examples are:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org (opensoure / free)
- https://www.wowza.com (commercial)

Building your own streaming server from scratch is probably not what your want to do.